# Multicolored Icon Fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, font-face

Since I have used Icon fonts, Its been a huge issue to have two colors with one class instead of a bunch of positioning or clipping.. since it is rather a common thing to have multicolored icons in a site, I came Across the solution today I thought I may just post this for people like me who looked for answers but only found complications...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay i am going to do this in a step-by-step manner:

**ILLUSTRATOR PART**

1. in illustrator copy the icon into a new document.
2. then cut the one color.
3. press save as and save as SVG
4. then paste the one you cut and delete the other one.
5. save as another SVG.

**ICOMOON**

1. Really is a great site.
2. start the app.
3. import the svg and download an save.

and then this is the CSS I used for a one class solution to multicolored font icons:

**CSS**

```
.icon-earth{
        font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.icon-earth:after {
    content: "\e006";
    color:#F33;
    font-size:6em;

}
.icon-earth:before {
    content: "\e007";
    color:#0C0;
    font-size:6em;
    letter-spacing:-1em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon-earth"></div>
```

its quiet easy to interpret the CSS for you own needs, if help is need please shout and I will go through this step by step aswell...

And Finally Here is the **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/86gGD/)**, although i cant get custom Icon Fonts happening in JsFiddle...

Browser support is IE8 and up and then everything else i have checked..

Comment: This will only work for 2 colors icon. But what if my icon has 3 colors or more??

Comment: Hey @GilEpshtain did not expect thats flashback from 6ish years ago, honestly I would just use SVG's in nowadays but if icon fonts is a must then you could follow the same process I guess just using more then one html element and absolute positioning. But my requirement at the time was luckily only 2 colors.

Comment: I can't use the same process, since there's only 2 places to insert color `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: @GilEpshtain thats why I mentioned using more than 1 html element with absolute positioning: `<div class="icon-earth"><div class="inner-earth-icon"></div></div>` that you you can get 4 places to insert color.